Almost volume cone implies almost metric cone
I am reading this paper by Wenshuai Jiang and Guofang Wei, about finite diffeomorphism types under Ricci curvature lower bound. In the proof, "almost volume cone implies almost metric cone" got by Cheeger and Colding is needed.
My question is how can we understand this almost volume cone implies almost metric cone theorem in geometric sense without proof?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

You need to be careful on the volume cone condition, it's not quite same as what you would see in Cheeger-Colding's "Warped Products" paper or Cheeger's "Degeneration" book, even if you removed the negative log properly.
Simply speaking, the Bishop-Gromov volume comparison gives you a non-increasing volume ratio, but you don't know how fast it decay. The volume cone you see is saying that the ratio is almost constant from radius 1 to radius 2.
By some algebra you can see that the small radius is not that important, you can find a "new" volume cone condition that only talks to one radius, due to monotonicity.
Let me know if you need me to explain more. I just created this account because I am happy to meet anyone who is also reading this paper, and I want to chat with you, but I feel like I need some time to learn about how to use MSE first:)
